# How to unwrap a 3D mesh such that the dimensions are preserved

Tags: graphics, 3d, 2d

Imagine you have a papercrafted circle in real life and put in on your forearm. This curved object now represents a 3D object. I need to map this 3D object back to its original 2D shape by unwrapping the 3D object.

I have looked into LSCM and angle-based flattening but they are in need of the geometrical faces of the object, which i dont have.

Is there anything out which could solve my problem?

Comment: How is your object represented numerically, then ?

Comment: circle is a planar (flat) object not curved one did you mean sphere instead? or curved surface (no volume). What do yo know about your objects .... if you do not have mesh (points,faces) then what you have: camera image? algebraic representation? volumetric representation?

Comment: I am talking about a curved surface without a volume. All i know are the most outward points of the surface (think about concave hull) and their edges to each other. Imagine you have the circle and my object would be a set of points and edges which lies at the circumference. If now one side would be elevated (by bending for example), I would like to analytically project the (now 3d) shape into its original 2d circle shape.

Comment: @ThinhTran that is not projection but straighting because after projection the shape would be different than the original one. If you got bended surface like paper not distorted one so surface area is still the same then the bending obey material consistency rules. That mean if you find axis of bending you can unbend it back ...  So if you got the points in vector form and in scale (not projected or just image) is this doable. But if the surface is stretched then no this is not doable without additional info/input. You should add a sample input ...

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to look for in an existing method. So basically any UV wrapping methods without the need of faces and for arbitrary shapes. It is not trivial to find the axis of bending because in a curved circle ( which preserves the surface volume) you have an inifnite count of bending axis.